# HTML Open link in New tab button

Tags: html

I am trying to make a button to lead to a page in HTML, except, the thing I use for hosting runs sites inside an iframe, I can make a button to lead to a page, but it will refuse to load because it is in an Iframe, so I need to find a way to make a button, that opens a link **in a new tab**. But I cannot find any information online on how to do it. My code is available  here:https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFUY1Y8E6WB2. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see your code in that link. Please use jsfiddle or codepen or something else to host your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabliy the easiest way is to use an `<a>` tag as follows

```html
<a href="https://website.com" target="_blank"><button>Button Content</button></a>
```

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.
Using "_blank", the linked document in opened in a new window or tab.
More information is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).